# Integrating Smartfocus connector and Salesforce

Tags: integration

Has anyone integrated Salesforce with smartfocus?

http://developer.smartfocus.com/docs/read/SmartFocus_Connector_for_Salesforce

We have an Integration in place, but when i add new fields, the data synchronization is failing. Don't know what the reason is.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was FLS not set for the fields mapped at Sales force side and for that reason data mapping was failing.and So did synchronization.Once FLS was set ,synchronization was happening and things started working